# Compare of imported databasea - (Fingerprinting possible?)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, ms-access-2010

**Source**: MS Access on Windows network share

**Target**: MySQL/MariaDB on Ubuntu

**Tools**: mdb-export, mysqlimport

**record count**: 1,5 Mio +

I wonder if there is a fast and reliable way of comparing the imported data records.

Is there an SQL standard equivalent to e.g. md5 fingerprint hashes of files? Right now, I am building different import routines and I only want to fast check for similarity and (if failed) search for the detailed differences later on.

Comment: NO, but a simple row count would seem to be the perfect FastCheck

Comment: Sorry, row count is not enough. The Biggest Problems are (as always) date formatting, special characters and decimal delimiters.

Comment: As you are writing imports, then the dates should be sorted as part of that, special characters will be handled by using the correct utf collations, and numbers with decimals are stored with a `.` for the decimal seperator and NO thousand seperator. If you happen to be showing numbers in one of the coutries that do the decimal and thousand the wrong way round, thats the job of the presentation layer, not the database storage

Comment: There certainly isn't. I've written a "random compare 1000 rows" in VBA with an epsilon for dates and floats to accept floating point errors. An alternate approach is to do Access -> CSV and mariadb -> CSV with the same settings, then MD5 the CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat of a quick-and-dirty approach for individual columns can be implemented using [stored aggregate functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/) which should be SQL standard.

This is how you'd do it with MariaDB:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS my_checksum(x TEXT) RETURNS CHAR(40)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE cksum CHAR(40) DEFAULT SHA1('');
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
 RETURN cksum;
      LOOP
          FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
          SET cksum = SHA1(CONCAT(cksum, x));
      END LOOP;
END
```

You can then calculate a checksum from of a column as such:

```
MariaDB [test]> create or replace table t1(data varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.063 sec)

MariaDB [test]> create or replace table t2(data varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.064 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t1 values ('hello'), ('world'), ('!');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.011 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> insert into t2 values ('Hello'), ('World'), ('!');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.015 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select my_checksum(data) from t1;
+------------------------------------------+
| my_checksum(data)                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| 7f6fb9a61c2097f70a36254c332c47364c496e07 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select my_checksum(data) from t2;
+------------------------------------------+
| my_checksum(data)                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| 5f683ea3674e33ce24bff5f68f53509566ad4da2 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> delete from t2;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.011 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t2 values ('hello'), ('world'), ('!');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.012 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select my_checksum(data) from t2;
+------------------------------------------+
| my_checksum(data)                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| 7f6fb9a61c2097f70a36254c332c47364c496e07 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

This of course relies on the SHA1 of the column being the same on all databases. Conversions into strings should make it mostly compatible but there might be differences in how these are implemented in different databases.

Answer (score 0):

The percona toolkit has the tool you need.

https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/

See `pt-table-checksum` and `pt-table-sync`

Answer (score -1):

I found it.

It's very simple and very fast.

```
CHECKSUM TABLE tbl_name
```

Will give you a number value to compare.

And it's Transact-SQL so will hopefully work the same on MS Access, MySQL and MariaDB

Comment: Nope, won't work at all, it's just for T-SQL and due to different storage approaches used for dates even if both implemented a checksum they wouldn't be the same

Comment: You are right. Just realized that MS Access is lacking CHECKSUM. I have to build something on my own.